# Programs keep configuring upon launch

Tags: windows

I am attempting to assist users in my environment who have are having issues with applications(vmware viewer, ms office etc) configuring/installing themselves upon launch. Could it be an issue with the image the company is using that is creating this?

Comment: So the configure is happening every time the same user launches the application?

Comment: Yes they are getting it on the launch of the application. Seems to be isolated to two applications vmware viewer and ms office

Comment: Is this a class room? Is some type of freeze software being used? If so then every time the system is rebooted it will come up at the same point where the ops have just been installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not literally "the image," but it's probably due to the other things they're doing to maintain the image and/or consistent user state.

Is the configure happening on each run, once per login, or what? If once per login (what I'd expect), see if there's a mandatory profile in place for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` that is missing one or more critical values. Also check if `%appdata%` or similar folders are getting wiped on a new login, on reboot, or whenever.

If I'm correct, find a way to make those values or files are available on first run. Either modifying the mandatory profile, copying critical files or settings into `%appdata%` or similar via login script, etc.